# nginx rewrite rule to convert URL segments to query string parameters

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm setting up an nginx server for the first time, and having some trouble getting the rewrite rules right for nginx.

The Apache rules we used were:

See if it's a real file or directory, if so, serve it, then send all requests for `/` to `Director.php`

```
DirectoryIndex Director.php
```

If the URL has one segment, pass it as `rt`

```
 RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/$ /Director.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If the URL has two segments, pass it as `rt` and `action`

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/$ /Director.php?rt=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]
```

My nginx config file looks like:

```
server {
...

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}    

location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

How do I get the URL segments into Query String Parameters like in the Apache rules above?

**UPDATE 1**

Trying Pothi's approach:

```
# serve static files directly
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
   access_log off;
   expires 30d;
}


location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /Director.php;
   rewrite "^/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/$" "/Director.php?rt=$1" last;
   rewrite "^/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/$" "/Director.php?rt=$1&action=$2" last;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_index  index.php;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

This produces the output `No input file specified.` on every request. I'm not clear on if the `.php` location gets triggered (and subsequently passed to php) when a rewrite in any block indicates a .php file or not.

**UPDATE 2**

I'm still confused on how to setup these location blocks and pass the parameters.

```
location /([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/ {
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_index  index.php;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  ${document_root}Director.php?rt=$1{$args};
   include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

It looks like the root directive was missing, which caused the `No input file specified.` message. Now that this is fixed, I get the index file as if the URL were `/` on every request regardless of the number of URL segments.

It appears that my location regular expression is being ignored.

My current config is:

```
# This location is ignored:
location /([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/ {
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_index  Director.php;
   set $args $query_string&rt=$1;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include        fastcgi_params;
}

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /Director.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_index  Director.php;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete `server` block.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: None of the following are tested. Please use it with caution. If anything goes wrong, please turn on debugging as mentioned at http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html .

```
See if it's a real file or directory, if so, serve it,
then send all requests for / to Director.php
```

This may be achieved with...

```
server {
  index Directory.php;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /Directory.php;
  }
}
```

The `index` directive is enough for directory index. To send all requests to Director.php, then location block is needed.

```
If the URL has one segment, pass it as rt
```

You may try the following...

```
rewrite "^/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/$" "/Director.php?rt=$1" last;
```

Please remember the quotes around the rewrites. It is preferable to use quotes, and is needed on certain conditions (that is mentioned in the link provided earlier by @jerm).

```
If the URL has two segments, pass it as rt and action
```

You may try the following...

```
rewrite "^/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/$" "/Director.php?rt=$1&action=$2" last;
```

Please note that I haven't done anything for QSA in the above examples. You may try `$args` variable in Nginx to pass the existing query string to the new query string. Ref: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables

I hope that helps to arrive at the full working solution!

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I tried using it as a model (please see Update #1 above), but I get `No input file specified` on every request.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good primer on capturing regexes as variables in nginx locations

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names

Comment: I get the basics of it, but do I need a location block for one segment and another location block for 2 segments? And do I need `fastcgi_pass` in each of those blocks?

Comment: yes and yes.... You might be tempted to use an "if" statement to do this in once location block, but be sure to read why if is evil: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: Please see my update #2 above- I'm still not sure how to pass the captured value of the regex as a Query String parameter. And also how to append any existing Query string, like Apache's `QSA` option.